# Look at the picture, what has the same function as this sentence?

Tags: rebus

The second puzzle of a rebus series.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

May it be:

> The Treachery of Images ("This is not a pipe").

As in my opinion:

> The arrow means "This", the ist(en) can be interpreted as "is" (ist is the german for is) but it is erased then "is not" and the green "pipe". Thus, "This is not a pipe" as it is also known the painting "The Treachery of Images".

Comment: I think this is a good answer. The inclusion of a different language fits as the original was in French.